# Logout from Fabric Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I want to logout from Fabric Plugin used in Android Studio. Clicking on Profile icon is not working but I need to switch account in there for another project. 
What to do?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Launch the Fabric plugin in Android studio. After loading it, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and It will make you log out.

Comment: i wish there was visible button somewhere

Comment: It is the worst user experience I have encountered in recent times. I cant directly inject the SDK to my app, I have to launch the app via the plugin and the plugin doesn't have a Log out button! How crazy is that?? I wish Google play Beta supported non gmail accounts. I would never use Fabric.

Comment: May those developers suffer in hell... I spent half an hour, removing ~/.AndroidStudio, project files and etc

Comment: I don't really understand. How developers in this level could be so dumb? I mean, it's a very simple requirement for a person to be able to VISUALLY sign out of a system. This is the a-b-c of the alphabet. How could they miss this?

Comment: Haha I actually even reinstalled it hoping it'd log me out before seeing this answer :D

Comment: I am a Software Developer. Holds a B.Tech degree in Computer Science. The world already thinks me next to GOD and then I need to search this.

Answer (score 19):

1. In **Android Studio**, Click on `Fabric` icon.
2. In **Eclipse**, Click on the `Fabric` on Eclipse task bar *so that the Fabric window is in focus.*
3. For **Windows/linux** User Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and For **MAC** Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. `optional` If fabric doesn't logout, you need to restart your IDE.

Comment: Why it is so complicated?

Comment: I think its most easy way to log out from Fabric plugin in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, it is easy indeed. I was commenting the fact that Fabric plugin does not offer any other intuitive way to log out. I mean, so 'log out' button in somewhere visible. But this shortcut is very useful and easy.

Comment: It may be easy but the question is why not simply have a logout button. It took me 2 reinstalls and 1 hour of search to figure this dam stuff.

Comment: @Trinity to proof it is a developer-oriented tool.